# Dynamic event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Would like to have a dynamic event handler for each "button" class. Handler must on click show the content of the "neighbour" column. I was thinking of tagging the content with class, e.g. "pictures-content", "video-content" and when looping over all buttons classes the first "picture-content" or "video-content" class would be the target for showing on click. Or is there any better .. smoother solution for this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7" >
        <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1" >
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="news line">
                <!-- Button for displaying Video content --> 
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button"> Show</a> 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5" >
        <div class="col-md-11 video">
            <div class="col-md-12 video-content">
            <!-- Video content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ps: I am using bootstraps 3, if that matters.

Comment: What JS do you have so far?

Comment: None .. but pseudo code would be very simple .. ''' for each button: find first video or picture content .. generateEvent .. on click show this content '''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind event, like

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.video-content').show();
});
```

Comment: So creating such HTML structure is fine? I am far from experienced in web development.

Comment: @krizajB, It can be improved, but as you are starting out things will come. Its very hard to say by just view a sample code but you reduce no of divs

Comment: How to create OR (||) here? i.e video-content or picture-content. Just call `$(this).closest('.row').find('.video-content').show();` `$(this).closest('.row').find('.pictures-content').show();` ?

Comment: @krizajB, yep that's the way only take care of correct classes name or id if you are using them

Comment: @krizajB, you can use `.find('.video-content,.picture-content')`

Answer (score 2):

Using classes is good.

Your pattern should be to get the parent `.row` and then from there get `.video-content`.

Try this:

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.video-content,.picture-content').show();
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sKS9J/1/)